# One to one relationship or another approach?

Tags: database-design

I need some addition thoughts on how to approach a database design I'm working on.  The issue is I have three related items...

```
* Clan (has many games)
* Game (belongs to a clan, has many teams)
* Team (belongs to a game)

Clan -< Game -< Team
```

Each of them is also treated as a "Site" and they can only ever have one site.  Each site has a standard set of properties, but Clan / Game / Team each have their own unique properties.  It's like Clan, Game & Team are subtypes of a Site.  How would I best model this in a database as the relationships go?

Idea 1: A 1-to-0/1 relationship between multiple tables (doesn't feel like it's a good idea).

```
Sites
  object_id (primary key, uuid)
  + additional site properties
Clan
  object_id (primary key, foreign key sites.object_id)
  + additional team properties
Game
  object_id (primary key, foreign key sites.object_id)
  + additional team properties
Team
  object_id (primary key, foreign key sites.object_id)
  + additional team properties
```

Idea 2: Clan, Game & Team each have a column "site_id" that is a foreign key to "site.id".  This makes sense but doesn't provide a way in the database to enforce one Clan/Game/Team per site.

Idea 3: A relationship table, (id, item_type [clan,game,team], item_id, site_id), with a unique constraint on the site_id.  I'm sure this is a "no-no" as I can't do any foreign keys on item_id.

Idea 4: Multiple relationship tables (clan_site, team_site, game_site), still doesn't solve limiting a site to only one item.

Idea 5: Have clan_id, game_id and team_id columns added to the site table.  Although this would work for foreign keys, it doesn't seem right as only one of those columns would hold a value.  Can't think of a way to stop two or more columns being populated and since NULL is supposed to be unknown, would that mean I should really have: clan_id = 2, game_id = 0, team_id = 0 ?

I'm probably missing something obvious or looking at this from the wrong side. :)

Comment: U mean that every recode in every table has one site or 3 table together have one site?

Comment: A clan can have a site, so can a game and a team, but they cannot share a single site.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I've just stumbled across a response by the mighty @BillKarwin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922184/why-can-you-not-have-a-foreign-key-in-a-polymorphic-association on a similar topic.  Looks like there are three "proper" approaches: Exclusive Arcs (multiple foreign keys), Reverse the relationship (not sure if that makes sense for this) or a Supertable (similar to the UUID idea).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove extra fields the best approach (In my eye of course) would be to insert site_id to clan,team and game tables.

In the site table we have site_id which is primary key(unique) and we have a field in the name of url.

> - url field should be unique.
> - one-to-one relationship between your three tables with site table.

This is the way to go.

Comment: That idea sits pretty well with me, but my only stumbling block comes when I want to find out what "type" a site is.  I think have to check three tables for the site id.  Maybe I'm trying too hard to do this the "right" way and should just settle for a "polymorphic association"... my head hurts :/

Comment: yes @MisterDai U have to check three tables for the site id, but if you join tables and just fetch the site_id from those three table, the result will be fast.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Idea 1" is the best approach as it most naturally and accurately enforces the cardinality between SITE and CLAN/GAME/TEAM.

Your other rule that SITE must be only one of CLAN, GAME or TEAM would have to be enforced with a partitioning attribute on SITE, e.g.: SITE.subtype_code.

You would need either application logic or a trigger to enforce consistency between the partitioning attribute and the existence of a record in either CLAN, GAME or TEAM.

Answer (score 1):

Two variations on what you name "idea 1":

```
Site
  site_id   primary key
  + additional site properties
Clan
  clan_id   primary key, foreign key site(site_id)
  + additional clan properties
Game
  game_id   primary key, foreign key site(site_id)
  clan_id   foreign key clan(clan_id)
    unique key (clan_id, game_id)
  + additional game properties
Team
  team_id   primary key, foreign key site(site_id)
  clan_id
  game_id
    foreign key (clan_id, game_id)
      references game(clan_id, game_id)
  + additional team properties
```

If you want to be finding easily what type every site is (without searching all 3 subtype tables):

```
Site
  site_id   
  site_type
    primary key (site_id, site_type)
    check site_type IN ('C', 'G', 'T')
  + additional site properties
Clan
  clan_id
  site_type    default 'C'
    primary key (clan_id, site_type)
    foreign key (clan_id, site_type)
      references site(site_id, site_type)
  + additional clan properties
Game
  game_id   
  site_type    default 'G'
    primary key (game_id, site_type)
    foreign key (game_id, site_type)
      references site(site_id, site_type)
  clan_id   foreign key clan(clan_id)
    unique key (clan_id, game_id)
  + additional game properties
Team
  team_id   
  site_type    default 'T'
    primary key (team_id, site_type)
    foreign key (team_id, site_type)
      references site(site_id, site_type)
  clan_id
  game_id
    foreign key (clan_id, game_id)
      references game(clan_id, game_id)
    unique key (clan_id, game_id, team_id)
  + additional team properties
```

Comment: Thanks ypercube.  Having the site type flag in the site table would make life easier.  I'll probably be lazy loading records so it'd save queries to each table.  Thanks for the help :)